# Comparison between entropy and internal energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

Why is entropy change a better way of determining a spontaneous process compared to the change in internal energy?

Comment: There is a law of Thermodynamics that tells us something about the direction in which entropy evolves. Does that give you a hint?

Answer (score 2):

The change in internal energy is not a relevant quantity for spontaneous evolution of a system. Consider an isolated system made of two blocks of the same material at two different temperatures such that $T_1>T_2$. Heat will flow from $1$ to $2$ but the total change in internal energy is $\Delta U_{1+2}=0$. This information is therefore not useful.

On the other hand, the change in total entropy is  $\Delta S_{1+2}=Q/T_2-Q/T_1>0$ and can tell us about the direction of the process.

Answer (score 1):

Entropy change is not better nor worse than any other quantity obtained from a Legendre transformation, but its applicability when is convenient is different. If the system is isolated (internal energy is constant) and some internal constraints are relaxed then entropy is *maximized* when equilibrium is reestablished. On the other hand, if the interaction is such that the entropy is kept constant then internal energy is *minimized* in equilibrium. While these two conditions are completely equivalent mathematically constant entropy - minimum energy interaction is difficult to achieve in practice, but constant energy - maximum entropy is easy.

Answer (score -2):

because G=H_TS, and entropy of system at constant pressure must increase if its enthalpy remains constant and know that we've a spontaneous reaction when ¤s>0,

Comment: This is not even a whole sentence. It should probably rather be a comment than an answer (once you have enough reputation, you can comment on any post). Otherwise, please expand your answer and elaborate on your point.